# Python - how to use few times the same next iteration?

Tags: python, list, loops, iterator

I would like to search a list:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

and replace/edit items different from the previous item and next item. For xxample: I want to get rid of/edit `1` at index 2 in the list above.

Take a look at my code below and please continue reading my core question beneath my code:

**!Update:** Result should be: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

```
x = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
print(x)
hiter = iter(x)
next(hiter)
prev = None

for i in x:
    try:
        print('prev %s - CURRENT %s - next %s' % (prev, i, next(hiter)))
        prev = i

        #if i != prev and i != next(hiter):
        #   x[i] = prev 

    except StopIteration:
        break

print(x)
```

We know the previous item, the next item and the current item.

But everytime I use:

```
if i != prev and i != next(hiter)...
```

the `next(hiter)` destroys order. In other words, if I use `next(hiter)` more than 1 time in my loop, Python reads the next item as double, because I used `next(hiter`) two times in a loop.

I tried also declare seperate variable like `y = next(hiter)` - but still it didn't work (obviously won't work but I was desperate to check it anyway xD).

I have no clues, in addition, `hiter.__next__()` does the same as `next(hiter)`.

Comment: Why not iterate over the indices instead of the objects? Rather than `for i in x`, iterate with `for i in range(len(x))`, and access the elements with `x[i]`. You will be able to access `x[i-1]` and `x[i+1]` without consuming them like with `next`.

Comment: Could you include the "expected output"? What about the zeros at index 3 and 7?

Comment: unless I'm misunderstanding this seems like a complicated way to approach what seems to be a simple problem, please clarify your question and output

Comment: Besides, `next(x)` executes itself `x.__next__()`.

Comment: You will not be able to modify the original list if you iterate over it instead of indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making this too complicated on yourself. Instead, just read `x` multiple times within your loop:

```
for idx in range(1, len(x)-1): # Consider using enumerate, it's a great idea
    curr = x[idx]
    prev = x[idx - 1]
    nxt = x[idx + 1]
    if (curr != prev) and (curr != nxt):
        print('prev %s - CURRENT %s - next %s' % (prev, curr, nxt))
```

Comment: You can cache the values of the current and next item instead of accessing them from `x`. Aside from that, this is a reasonable solution.

Comment: if you think enumerating is better, show how to. and though **I'm not the DVoter**, I believe it comes from the reason that you  chose to offer another solution without any explanation, disregarding the work OP has done. this is usually looked down upon.

Comment: I would frankly hope that my code is fairly self-evident. I agree that enumerate would have been cleaner (though I disagree that caching would be cleaner, even if I do realise it'd be faster code). Didn't think this to be the right forum for the use case of enumerate, though.

Comment: @acdr, I didn't understand the OP problem at first, so I thought you solution was wrong, sorry, my mistake, I did a little change (in the comment), so I could upvote

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generator that keeps the previous item and looks one item ahead:

```
def gen(x):
    x = iter(x)
    # Get the first item and simply yield it
    first = next(x)
    yield first

    # create a list containing the previous element, the current element and the next element
    # and iterate over your input.
    three = [None, first, next(x)]
    for item in x:
        # Update the list of elements: Remove the previous previous item and
        # add the new next item.
        three = three[1:] + [item]
        prev, cur, nxt = three

        if cur != prev and cur != nxt:
            three[1] = prev  # replace the current item with the previous item
            yield prev

        else:
            yield cur

    # Simply yield the last item
    yield three[-1]


>>> list(gen([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

In this approach I simply returned the first and last item without checks because the only have a next or previous item not both. You could put some checks there as well if you like.

As @MadPhysicist pointed out one doesn't need the list at all, you could simply use a variable for the `previous`, `current` and `next` item:

```
def gen(x):
    x = iter(x)
    # Get the first item and simply yield it
    first = next(x)
    yield first

    cur, nxt = first, next(x)  # Initial current and next item
    for item in x:
        prev, cur, nxt = cur, nxt, item  # Update the previous, current and next item

        if cur != prev and cur != nxt:
            cur = prev
            yield prev

        else:
            yield cur

    # Simply yield the last item
    yield nxt
```

---

NB: Both approaches will create a new list and don't modify the original list.

Comment: Best answer. You can probably remove the need for `three` completely and just use `prev`, `cur`, `nxt`. The update would be `prev, cur, nxt = cur, nxt, item`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to access your list elements via indexing. In your loop you can then access the previous and next items by adding or subtracting to the current index.

Remember that in a list you can access an element with `hiter[0]`, `hiter[1]`, ..., and in the loop as:

```
for i in range(len(hiter)-1):
    print("The item is %s" % hiter[i])
```

and so you can then access the previous and next, only needing to take care of the edge cases (to keep the index from moving out of range). An approach would be:

```
for i in range(len(hiter)):
    if 0 < i < (len(hiter) - 1):
        print("The items are %s, %s, %s" % (hiter[i-1], hiter[i], hiter[i+1]))
    elif i == 0:
        print("The items are %s, %s" % (hiter[i], hiter[i+1]))
    elif i == (len(hiter) - 1):
        print("The items are %s, %s" % (hiter[i-1], hiter[i]))
```

In the same fashion, you can change the values in your mutable list with the same indexing methods.

Comment: Why do you even need to use an iterator if you are using it like a list? Just use `x` as-is.

Comment: I'm trying to make it apparent what is going on....I'm certain that there are plenty of ways to skin this cat, but I've tried to put on the stabilizers for this one :)

Comment: Sounds like an unnecessary layer of complication to me.

Answer (score -1):

There's a [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) function that allows to "clone" iterators.

```
iter1, iter2 = itertools.tee(iter(<iterable>))
```

Your case seem too trivial - unless it's just the example, to use it

*EDIT*
In that case

```
for index, val in enumerate(x[1:-1], 1)
    if val != x[index-1] and val != x[index+1]:
        x[index] = x[index-1]
```

Comment: How will this allow OP to actually solve the initial problem of editing the items in the list?

Answer (score -1):

**!Update 2:** Thank You everyone for contribution. It was really helpful and I learned a lot today. Here is what I meant (Sorry @MSeifert but I had to do it my way, I know generators are faster and they don't eat memory). 
Solution:

```
x = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
print(x)
for i in range(1, len(x)-1):
    current = x[i]
    nxt = x[i+1]
    prev = x[i-1]

    if current != prev and current != nxt:
        print('prev: %s - CURRENT: %s - next: %s [ X ]' % (prev, current, nxt))
        x[i] = x[i-1]
    else:
        print('prev: %s - CURRENT: %s - next: %s' % (prev, current, nxt))

print(x)
```

Comment: The range should start from 1, not 0.

Comment: You should probably accept [@acdr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44393373/5393381) then (see ["How does accepting an answer work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)). It seems that is the answer that helped you most (the approach seems roughly identical). You can also upvote all answers that you found helpful. :) Self-answering the question should only be done if your approach significantly differs from already existing answers. :)

Comment: done :) 
sorry Im new here, and a lil bit lost on this great forum yet.

Comment: @Mad Physicist Indeed, because we start from 2nd index so It can read "previous" properly. Thank You.